# Why do some mammals have incomplete orbits?

Tags: evolution, zoology, eyes, mammals, bone-biology

I've noticed that a lot of carnivorous/omnivorous mammals (*most, if not all the members of carnivora and some ancestral cetaceans*), as well as some herbivores (*marsupials*), have incomplete orbits that merge into the temple near the zygomatic arch. I'm wondering what the evolutionary purpose of this is, as well as why we would lack them.

Comment: not some, most mammals have incomplete orbits. only a few groups have closed it. It seems to be related to the position of the temporal fossa. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15844100 the whole region varies quite a lot in mammals https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18211281

Comment: Some things to think about are the size of the field of view, the protection of the eye, and the normal orientation of the head.